# Is it "a globalization" or "globalization"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, articles

The phrase I intend to use it for is:

> Apart from **a globalization** in my worldview, ...

The above reads better to me than:

> Apart from **globalization** in my worldview, ...

But I've never seen an article being used with "globalization".
Am I using the word correctly? Could someone suggest another word, if not?
Thanks.

Comment: The second one is better.

Comment: Would you say 'there has been a tightening of border controls' or 'there has been tightening of border controls'? If this is a one-off change, the indefinite article is appropriate.

Comment: Depends on the wider context.

Answer (score 0):

Globalization can be a countable and an uncountable noun.  While I can think of sentences where "globalizations" might be used, I cannot think of one where "a globalization" might be used.

https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/globalization.html

*The noun globalization can be countable or uncountable.

In more general, commonly used, contexts, the plural form will also be globalization.

However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be globalizations e.g. in reference to various types of globalizations or a collection of globalizations.*